# How to prevent recursive windows when connecting to vncserver on localhost

Tags: vnc, loopback

I have a VNCServer (vino) configured on my Ubuntu 8.10 box. I would like to connect to this server from a vncclient running on this same machine (the reason for doing this strange thing is mentioned below).

Understandably, when I connect to a vncserver on the same box, my vncclient shows recursive windows.

Is there a way I can connect to the vncserver on the same machine and not have the recursive windows problem? Perhaps if I could start the vncserver on one display and the client on another display then will it work? How can I do something like this?

***Note - Reason for running vnc client and server on the same machine:***
When I start our Java Swing unit test suite, a bunch of swing UI's are created and destroyed as the tests run. These windows fly in the foreground making it impossible to work while the test suite is running. I am hoping to start the test suite within a vncclient so that I can continue working while the tests run.

***Update***

Some searching seems to suggest that I can start a process on another display. I tried doing this to start vncviewer on another display.

```
export DISPLAY=:1
vncviewer localhost:0
```

but I get an error -

> Error: Can't open display: :1

Does anyone know why I get this error message (I am running Ubuntu 8.10)?

Comment: Have you considered Xvfb or xephyr?

Comment: you get the error message because you don't _have_ another display. use xvfb or xephyr to _get_ another display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Xvfb](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html) or [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr) to create another (virtual) display and then tell your application to use *that* display.

Forget about VNC.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xnest:

```
Xnest :1.0 &
DISPLAY=1.0 xlogo
```

Comment: Xnest is considered obsolete and supplanted by Xephyr.